# Get data from Smartwatch Android Wear to Smartphone

Tags: android, wear-os, sony-smartwatch, moto-360

I have made some apps (pedometer, heart rate, audio recorder) for the moto360 with android wear. everything works fine, but I don't know how to save the data on the watch and how to access the data on the smartphone. I have managed to send messages to the watch, but I can't send data from the watch to the phone. I can save my data on the smartphone, but I don't know how to manage it on the smartwatch. can someone show me a tutorial or an example? thank you so much!

edit:
The following Code below is used for tracking the heartrate on the Moto360 and it works fine.
I tried to transfer the data from the watch to the Phone for that I used this tutorial -> https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html

After implementing the Code from the android page I  couldn`t run the Project on the device!

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {


        private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
        private TextView mTextViewStepCount;
        private TextView mTextViewStepDetect;
        private TextView mTextViewHeart;
        PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
            stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

                    mTextViewStepCount = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.step_count);
                    mTextViewStepDetect = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.step_detect);
                    mTextViewHeart = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.heart);
                    getStepCount();

                }
            });
        }

        private void getStepCount() {
            SensorManager mSensorManager = ((SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE));
            Sensor mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
            Sensor mStepCountSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
            Sensor mStepDetectSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);

            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCountSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        private String currentTimeStr() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            return df.format(c.getTime());
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onAccuracyChanged - accuracy: " + accuracy);
        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
                String msg = "" + (int) event.values[0];

                mTextViewHeart.setText(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, msg);

            } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
                String msg = "Count: " + (int) event.values[0];
                mTextViewStepCount.setText(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
                String msg = "Detected at " + currentTimeStr();
                mTextViewStepDetect.setText(msg);
                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown sensor type");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you looked at this? http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html

Comment: yes and I have looked at this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataItem.html   but I don't know, what i should do with that

Comment: so then what specifically are you trying to send over?

Comment: for example: with the audio recorder is it possible to record the voice. I want to save this audio file with time stamp. and it should synchronize with my sqlite on smartphone app.

Comment: If you want to send something bigger than a few Strings / numbers, I'd recommend you use the Data API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this code helps me a lot, i hope it helps many other people :)

https://github.com/pocmo/SensorDashboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to uses data assets. Image sample:

```
private static Asset createAssetFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteStream);
    return Asset.createFromBytes(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```

and then

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
Asset asset = createAssetFromBitmap(bitmap);
PutDataRequest request = PutDataRequest.create("/image");
request.putAsset("profileImage", asset);
Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);
```

more http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

Comment: I posted my mainActivity file. I am not sure how to implement your Codesnippets in my Project. Thanks for helping me!!